# mssql order rows order by asc for all rows but last two rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by

need help with order by after union

```
select sno,measurement from measurementTable union all select '' as sno,avg(measurement) as 
measurement from measurementTable union all select '' as sno,
max(measurement)-min(measurement) from measurementTable;
```

I need to show average at the bottom of the datagrid, but order all other mssql server table rows ascending by sno
I tried to use order by before union all and got errors

```
select sno,measurement from measurementTable order by sno asc union all select '' as sno,
avg(measurement) as measurement from measurementTable union all select '' as sno,
max(measurement)-min(measurement) from measurementTable;

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'.
```

is it possible to use order by before union all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Order by` at the end of query it will apply to the entire result

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Cast(sno AS VARCHAR(20)) as sno,
               measurement
        FROM   measurementTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ''               AS sno,
               Avg(measurement) AS measurement
        FROM   measurementTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT '' AS sno,
               Max(measurement) - Min(measurement)
        FROM   measurementTable) A
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN sno = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ASC,sno
```

Convert the `sno` to `varchar` to avoid implicit conversion to `integer`

**Note :** If you can add sample data and expected result am sure query can be simplified using `ROLLUP`

Comment: thanks for kind reply, but I want to order only the `sno` for table values, and keep `avg(measurement)` and `max(measurement)-min(measurement)` at bottom of the query output. It takes '' as 0 for sno, and it goes to top of query output

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, I need those '0' to be hidden in the output. is it possible?

Comment: @user2801828 - Convert the `sno` to `varchar` to avoid implicit conversion to `integer`. Updated

Comment: Hi I have converted int to nvarchar(25) and changed your code from `case when sno`, to `case sno when`, it gives another error 
Msg 104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator.

Comment: @user2801828 - check now

Comment: hi thank you so much your code is working alright for nvarchar data

Answer (score -1):

just use

```
order by sno
```

at the end of your query.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to hide '0' from sno in output?

Comment: then you should use <pre>where sno!=0</pre>

Comment: I am not using php. is there an alternative way? thanks